# How to sum the total length of an array of uuids column

Tags: postgresql

Currently, I have 1 table consisting of id and otherIds
I want to calculate the sum of otherIds present in database.

```
id: 1, otherIds: {1,2,3,4,5}
id: 2, otherIds: {3,4,5}
id: 3, otherIds: {9,2,1}
id: 4, otherIds: {}
```

Desired result: 11 (5 + 3 + 3 + 0)

```
SELECT
   sum(jsonb_array_elements("table"."otherIds")) as "sumLength"
FROM
   "Table"
LIMIT 1
```

[42883] ERROR: function jsonb_array_elements(uuid[]) does not exist

Comment: That does not look like a JSONB value. What exactly is the column definition, and what are the values in the table rows? Please provide a [mcve] as SQL syntax (`CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how JSONB is relevant here. If `otherIds` is an array of `UUID` values then wouldn't you just need

```
SELECT
   SUM(ARRAY_LENGTH("table"."otherIds")) as "sumLength"
FROM
   "Table"
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I used this.
SELECT
   SUM(ARRAY_LENGTH("table"."otherIds", 1)) as "sumLength"
FROM
   "Table"
LIMIT 1

Comment: `array_length()` takes two parameters https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#id-1.5.8.25.6.2.2.5.1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of elements in an array with the `cardinality()` function. Just sum the results over all rows.

I'd like to remark that a table design that includes an array of UUIDs is not pretty and will probable gibe you performance and data integrity problems some day.